# Обрезать часть строки в Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Итак, есть некий dataframe, в котором одна из ячеек состоит из нескольких строк:

`Дата: июль\nОписание: игра на PS\nПодпись: game` . Необходимо выцепить 
`Описание: игра на PS` . Текст может быть и другой , главное начинать со слова `Описание`, а заканчивать ближайшим переносом строки `\n`

Comment: Маловато исходных данных:эта ячейка одна на весь df, или их целый столбец? и было бы очень хорошо привести пример собственно исходных данных и желаемого результата.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью [`extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) можете попробовать извлечь нужный текст.

```
In [32]: df
Out[32]: 
   col_1                                              col_2
0      1    Дата: июль\nОписание: игра на PS\nПодпись: game
1      2  Дата: июль\nОписание: другое описание\nПодпись...

In [33]: df['col_2'] = df['col_2'].str.extract('(Описание:.*)\n')

In [34]: df
Out[34]: 
   col_1                      col_2
0      1       Описание: игра на PS
1      2  Описание: другое описание
```